# Как отключить в Windows доступ к интернету от конкретного адаптера, сохранив доступ к локальной сети?

Tags: windows, windows-10, локальная-сеть

Есть ноутбук, подключенный к Ethernet и Wi-Fi одновременно. Нужно, чтобы при отключении от Ethernet ноутбук пользовался беспроводной сетью для доступа к локальным устройствам, но не мог через нее выходить в интернет. Это возможно настроить в Windows 10?

Comment: Вкратце, можно. Помогут статьи [Configuring Network Adapter with PowerShell](http://woshub.com/powershell-configure-windows-networking/) и [Использование Планировщика задач](https://ip-calculator.ru/blog/ask/kak-sozdat-zadanie-v-planirovshhike-zadach/). Создайте триггер события отключения интерфейса через управление оборудованием по EventID=6420,Audit Log, либо через драйвер сетевой, например, Source="ec1cexpress"+EventID=27, System Log. По активации он запускает скрипт, который задаст IP конфигурацию беспроводного интерфейса без шлюза с выходом в Интернет, либо включит ограничения файервола

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. На самом деле мне не нужно отключать интернет Wi-Fi в какой-то момент, он просто должен быть всегда выключен. Насколько я понял, достаточно указать неверный шлюз и свободный IPv4-адрес? Если так, то у меня нет никакой уверенности, что айпи, свободный сегодня, будет также свободен завтра. Это проблема или роутер сам найдет выход?